# Yet another .net custom cms

Tags: c#, content-management-system, domain-driven-design, .net

I'm trying to switch my custom cms written in php into .net c#. I was thinking to use cms as a learning project. I'm going to use C#, NHibernate ORM layer, mssql, mvc3 and jquery.

I'm aware there are plenty of commercials or open source cms, but still I'm going to spend some of my free time trying to learn new technology working on project like this.

So, is there anyone out there who is willing to share some ideas on creating cms domain model, usefull link, ideas, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A really basic CMS consist of 3 elements:

- one database table to hold your "pages". The table structure is "name" and "content"
- a route to transform requests of type `/cms/pagename` to a fixed controller, the method called `cms` and `pagename` as a parameter
- a embeddable html editor

Now, there are two ways your "page" can be invoked. It is either create mode or view/edit mode.

In "create" mode, the page is requested but it is not in the database yet (e.g. `cms/announcement1`). In this mode you create a view consisting of a html editor and upon submit, you persist the page to the database.

In "view" mode, the page is requested and is IS in the database. You perform any necessary rewriting (for example you rewrite internal links of the form `[cms/pagename]` to a fully routable http address) and render the content.

If the user is authorized to edit the page, you also show a "edit" button which then invokes the html editor with the page loaded and ready to be edited.

And that's it.

There are tons of additional elements (caching, different built-in page types, embedding images, youtubes, preformatted texts) etc. but all of them are optional and you can introduce new features when you have the core already implemented.

Once I wrote a simple CMS following the structure above, it was a part of a bigger solution and till now it's been sucesfully deployed several hundred times. An advantage of a custom CMS is that it can be really simple and easily maintanable.

Comment: If I understood correctly you have expirience in bulding custom cms. Is your system is plug-in enabled ? I'm very interested to build extendible system, no clue where to start.

Comment: Nope. There are some additional features involving file uploads/downloads and builtin page templates but no plugins.